# Cannot get syntax right for knockout and MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying Knockout for the first time and I am struggling to get it working.
The basic scenario is that I want to use autocomplete to add employees into a list. I want to be able to remove then as well. When the user is happy he can click submit and this will post the list of ids to the server where I move onto the next part of the process.
Currently I am trying to get the add employee to work first.

I have a server side view model class;

```
public class TrainingListEmployeesViewModel : BaseTrainingViewModel
{
    public TrainingListEmployeesViewModel()
    {
        this.EmployeeList = new List<int>();
        this.ClientEmployeeSelector = new ClientEmployeeSelector();
    }

    public TrainingListEmployeesViewModel(List<int> employeeList, string trainingName, string trainingDescription)
        : base(trainingName, trainingDescription)
    {
        this.EmployeeList = employeeList;
        var dates = new CalendarDates(Utility.GetToday(), Utility.GetToday().AddYears(1));
        this.Cvm = new CalendarViewModel(employeeList.ToList(), dates);
    }

    public List<int> EmployeeList { get; set; }

    public ClientEmployeeSelector ClientEmployeeSelector { get; set; }
}
```

}

The controller looks like this;

```
[HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Trainer, ManagerAccounts, ManagerIT")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [ValidateOnlyIncomingValuesAttribute]
        public ActionResult Training(TrainingViewModel tvm)
        {
            SessionObjects.TrainingName = tvm.TrainingName;
            SessionObjects.TrainingDescription = tvm.TrainingDescription;
            return this.RedirectToAction("Training", new { employeeId = tvm.EmployeeSelector.SearchTextId });
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, Trainer, ManagerAccounts, ManagerIT")]
        public ActionResult BulkTraining()
        {
            return this.View(new TrainingListEmployeesViewModel());
        }
```

The view looks like this;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SHP.Models.TrainingListEmployeesViewModel>" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Script.Serialization" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Bulk Training
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<form class="employeeListEditor">
    <h3>Allocate or cancel training for the selected employees</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Course Name</td>
            <td><%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.TrainingName) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: right;">Description (optional)</td>
            <td><%: Html.TextAreaFor(
               model => model.TrainingDescription, new { maxlength = "255", style = "width:400px;height:100px;" }) %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClientEmployeeSelector) %>
    <button data-bind="click: addEmployee">Add</button>
    <div id="displayEmployees" style="margin-top:10px;display: block">
        <table id="employeeDataTable" class="groupBorder">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Employee</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { viewModel.removeEmployee($data) }">Remove</a>
                        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: searchTextId"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><span data-bind="value: searchText"></span></td>
                </tr>               
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Employee(id, text) {
            var self = this;
            self.searchId = id;
            self.searchText = text;
        }

        var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
        function ViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.employees = ko.observableArray(initialData.EmployeeList);
            self.searchText = ko.observable(initialData.SearchText);
            self.searchTextId = ko.observable(initialData.SearchTextId);
            self.removeEmployee = function(employee) {
                this.employees.remove(employee);
            };
            self.addEmployee = function() {
                alert(self.searchText);
                this.employees.push(new Employee(self.searchTextId, self.searchText));
            };
            self.save = function() {
                ko.utils.postJson(location.href, { employees: self.employees });
            };
        }
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

The Editor Template looks like for ClientEmployeeSelector which contains autocomplete;

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SHP.Models.ClientEmployeeSelector>" %>

        <table class="groupBorder">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Enter 2 or more characters for "<%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SearchText)%>" and select from the list.</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.SearchText)%></td>
                <td><%: Html.AutocompleteFor(model => model.SearchText, controller: "Payroll",
                                            minLength: 2, maxResults: 10,
                                            htmlAttributes: new { style = "color:purple; width:500px;" })%>
                                <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SearchTextId)%>
                                <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SearchText)%>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I am getting an error message; the searchTextId is undefined. When I look at what is happening in the IE developer tools, the searchTextId exists OK, but it is impossible to find what the value of it is. So how can I get this working? I suspect I need to make a number of changes.

Comment: What's `Html.AutocompleteFor`? Where does this come from?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you bind wrong property. If you want to show table with employees you should use employee's properties in `foreach` binding. Also it is better to use `$parent` or `$root` objects in bindings instead of using `viewModel` object:

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeEmployee">Remove</a>
                <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: searchId"/>
            </td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: searchText"></span></td>
        </tr>               
    </tbody>
```

Here is working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/yXvDB/2/

But if you really want to show `searchTextId` property of view model in the employees table you should use `$parent` object:

```
<input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $parent.searchTextId"/>
```

Comment: My problem is with the add event so I need to make that clear in the question.

Comment: But add event is working in my code. What problem do you have with it?

Comment: I get this error message: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: 'searchTextId' is undefined;
Bindings value: value: searchTextId

Comment: Do you get this message after clicking Add button? Did you update your code according to my comments?

Comment: I don't think you made changes :(. You shouldn't have "value: searchTextId" binding on a page if you made changes. replace searchTextId with searchId in your binding.

Comment: Aha! you are right. Thank you for that! However the SearchText is not updating the table, I cannot see why that is.

Comment: Initially in your code you used value binding for span: <span data-bind="value: searchText">. Change this to text binding: <span data-bind="text: searchText">

Comment: That did not fix the problem. Every time I click add a new row is put in the table, and each row can be deleted. What is not working is that I cannot see the text for each row, as expected in the searchText field.

Comment: Do you see text in alert after click? If so you didn't change value binding to text binding for span.

Comment: From ie developer tools, this is the HTML for the new row of data. A remove link is displayed correctly, but neither of the databindings are being set for searchId and searchText; <tbody data-bind="foreach: employees">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeEmployee">Remove</a>
      <input value="" type="hidden" data-bind="value: searchId">
     </td>
     <td><span data-bind="text: searchText"></span></td>
    </tr>       
   </tbody>